# Send a POST request from Flask to PHP Script

Tags: javascript, php, python, jquery, flask

I'm trying to send a POST request to a PHP script from Flask. I am using a Datatables Editor to get information from a backend database. Datatables will send a POST request to get the data it needs when DOM is ready. However, I'm getting the following error:

> Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Here's the route:

```js
@bp.route('/my_php', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def php_post():
    url = 'http://localhost:5000/static/datatables-plugins/Editor-PHP-1.7.4/examples/php/staff.php'
    headers = {

        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'


    }
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(request.form).encode('utf-8')
    resp = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    return json.dumps(resp.content).encode('utf-8')
```

I think this may have to do with specifying allowed methods, however I don't know how to explicitly allow for GET/POST methods when a request for another URL is called *within* the Flask route.

Comment: The php script running may not allow other methods.
https://kite.com/python/docs/requests.post

Comment: The PHP script allows POST because it works when I run a test http server using sudo /usr/bin/php -S localhost:80. When I go to developer tools in Firefox, I can clearly see the POST request and return back from the PHP file.